# Can I use georeferenced jpeg raster as map layer in GeoJSON.io?

Tags: raster, openstreetmap, geojson, lidar, jpg

Can I use georeferenced .jpeg raster as map layer in GeoJSON.io?

I thought that I could, but it doesn't work.

I converted .tif raster visualization of LiDAR data to georeferenced jpeg. After this, I uploaded to server and when I pasted link in geojson.io -> Add map layer it didn't show anything. Jpeg is georeferenced in CRS WGS84.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it is code related. I have uploaded .jpeg file to friends server and map is accessible without problems. In geojson.io page you can add new map layer via Meta-Add map layer. There i enter link to .jpeg map and next i enter name of the map. But then map doesnt show up. At the right bottom it is ticked in the map legend. What am I missing?

Comment: Alright, I don't know the answer (sorry), but provide any information you think it would help; maybe a screenshot. And always use the edit button to update the question (I made some edits in your question to facilitate the reading; good luck).